# Listening And Recognizing at same time - Python Speech Recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I want to know that if it is possible for python speech recognition library to listen to audio(through microphone) and then recognize the words at same time because by default it first listens to audio source and after it is completed then only it starts to recognize it.

If this is not possible with speech_recognition library then can you suggest any other methods to do this?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684279/python-speechrecognition-word-by-word-continuous-output/60822575#60822575